# Prove that $\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{|x|}\right) - \frac{1}{1 + |x|}$ is always positive

Tags: derivatives, inequality

I have to study when the function
$$f'(x) = \ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{|x|}\right) - \frac{1}{1 + |x|}$$
is positive. I tried to use the inequality $\ln(1 + t) < t$, $\forall t > -1$ but this could not help me ($\frac{1}{|x|} - \frac{1}{1 + |x|}$ is always a positive quantity but I cannot say anything about $f'(x)$).

Is there a quick method? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for when the function $f'(x)$ is positive, or when the solution function $f(x)$ to the ODE is positive?

Comment: Get rid of the absolute value signs by breaking it up into $x \gt 0$ and $x \lt 0$.  Then just take the derivative.

Comment: @Angelica I don't think it can be the latter because you can subtract an arbitrary constant from any solution of the ODE to get another solution.

Comment: @TheoBendit I've tried using the Lambert W function but I got the expression $\frac{1}{|x|+1}e^{\frac{1}{|x|+1}} < \frac{1}{|x|}$ and I didn't not know how to continue (but this should be a quick inequality).

Answer (score 3):

Similarly to $\ln(1+t)\leq t$, we have a well-known inequality in the other direction:
$$\ln(1+t)\ge \frac{t}{1+t}\quad\text{for }t>-1 $$
with equality only if $t=0$. Plugging in $t=\frac{1}{|x|}\ne 0$ will give you $f'(x)>0$.

Comment: Did not know about this! Thanks!

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the upper estimate implies the lower estimate (and vice versa): $\ln(1+t) = - \ln \left( \frac{1}{1+t}\right)=- \ln \left(1- \frac{t}{1+t}\right)\ge \frac{t}{1+t} $.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x\neq 0$. For each $x\neq 0$, apply the mean value theorem to the function

$$f(u):=\ln{(u+|x|)}$$
on $[0,1]$.
You get

$$\frac{\ln{(1+|x|)}-\ln{|x|}}{1-0}=\frac{1}{t+|x|}$$
for some $0<t<1$. Notice that
$$\ln{(1+|x|)}-\ln{|x|}=\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\right)}$$
and that
$$\frac{1}{t+|x|}>\frac{1}{1+|x|}$$

Answer (score 1):

The function is simmetric in rispect to the $y$ axis. We can, thus, study the first derivate for $x>0$. We have:
$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}=-\frac{1}{x\cdot (1+x)}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}<0\,\,\,\forall x \in \mathbb{D}_{f'(x)}$$

Also:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=+\infty$$
And:
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0^+$$

So, in $(0,+\infty)$ the function is always positive and decreasing. In $(-\infty, 0)$, $f(x)$ is again always positive and increasing. Namely:
$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f(x)=0^+$$